# SQL Server Pivot - Como colocar o resultado de Dois Pivot na mesma Linha

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Gostaria de uma ajuda, onde não estou entendo o porque o resultado do pivot não exibi tudo na mesma linha. Se não der como eu poderia fazer. SQL Server

Query

```
select distinct codigocliente, NomeCliente, Gerencia, [MAT_Executivo], [Executivo],[MAT_Assistente],[Assistente],[MAT_OM] ,[OM] from
(
select 
ca.BK_Cliente          as codigocliente
,ca.DES_Cliente         as NomeCliente            
,ca.BK_EscritorioVenda  as Gerencia
,CASE WHEN ca.DES_CargoAnalista = 'ANALISTA'    THEN 'EXECUTIVO' ELSE DES_CargoAnalista END cargo
,CASE WHEN ca.DES_CargoAnalista = 'ANALISTA'    THEN 'MAT_EXECUTIVO' ELSE 'MAT_'+DES_CargoAnalista END MAT_Cargo
, ca.BK_ChaveRede
, ca.DES_NomeAnalista 
from dwh.bpms.rep_clienteanalista ca with (nolock)
) src
pivot (
max(DES_NomeAnalista)
for cargo in ([Executivo],[OM],[Assistente])
) pvt 
pivot (
max(BK_ChaveRede)
for mat_cargo in ([MAT_Executivo],[MAT_OM],[MAT_Assistente])
) pvt2


resultado 

    codigocliente   NomeCliente Gerencia    MAT_Executivo   Executivo   MAT_Assistente  Assistente  MAT_OM  OM
    
    0000002111  WEG VIND    NULL    NULL    US83852 JULIANA FELIX DE SOUZA  NULL    NULL
    0000002111  WEG VIND    US00348 ALBERSON FERNANDO PEDROSA OISHI NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Informe o Banco (MySql ou SqlServer) pois a solução muda conforme este.

Comment: É o Banco SQLServer

Answer (score 0):

Acho que uma alternativa para o seu caso é unir todos os valores na mesma coluna e utilizar o operador Pivot uma vez só.
Para unir os valores sugiro a utilização do operador Apply com o construtor de tabelas Values. Segue sugestão para testes:

```
select 
  codigocliente, 
  NomeCliente, 
  Gerencia, 
  [MAT_Executivo], 
  [Executivo],
  [MAT_Assistente],
  [Assistente],
  [MAT_OM],
  [OM] 
from
(
  select 
    ca.BK_Cliente          as codigocliente,
    ca.DES_Cliente         as NomeCliente,
    ca.BK_EscritorioVenda  as Gerencia,
    Coluna,
    Valor
  from dwh.bpms.rep_clienteanalista ca with (nolock)
  cross apply
  (
     select
     from 
     (
        values
          (CASE WHEN ca.DES_CargoAnalista = 'ANALISTA' THEN 'EXECUTIVO' ELSE DES_CargoAnalista END, ca.DES_NomeAnalista),
          (CASE WHEN ca.DES_CargoAnalista = 'ANALISTA' THEN 'MAT_EXECUTIVO' ELSE 'MAT_' + DES_CargoAnalista END, ca.BK_ChaveRede)
     ) v (Coluna, Valor)
  ) ap
) src
pivot 
(
  max(Valor) for Coluna in ([Executivo], [OM], [Assistente], [MAT_Executivo], [MAT_OM], [MAT_Assistente])
) pvt
```